# Mac menu item grayed out even though first responder responds to the corresponding selector

Tags: macos, cocoa, osx-yosemite, first-responder, nsviewcontroller

I have a refresh item in my menu, bound to first responder's `reload:` method. I have two view controllers. Both DO implement the exact same method with the same signature:

```
-(void)reload:(id)sth{
    ...
}
```

The menu item is bound the following way:

[image]

In one view controller, it works perfectly. In the other one, it's grayed out. Other menu items, custom or default, work fine. It's just one method in one view controller:

[image]

Why can it be grayed out?

Comment: How are you determining that the view is the first responder or in the responder chain above the first responder? If it really is in the responder chain, it could be that a) it implements `-validateMenuItem:` to return false for that item, or b) some other object closer to the first responder also implements the action method and *that* has implemented `-validateMenuItem:` to return false.

Comment: Also look for `validateUserInterfaceItem:`.

Comment: @KenThomases I haven't implemented that method. But after this, I've tried and it's not called.

Comment: Are you absolutely, positively sure that the action method in both view controller's is spelled identically and has the same case (i.e. all lowercase)? Also, what about my question about how you know it's the first responder or in the responder chain above it?